# Memory Manager Library: Static Or DLL/SO

Tags: c++, memory, cross-platform

I'm currently working on a cross platform C++ game engine (Windows, Mac, Ubuntu). I've finished writing a memory manager module that I would like the other modules to use. Ideally, there should only be one instance of the CMemoryManager class that oversees all the allocators (heaps, arenas etc...) This is then passed to the managers from other modules (input, graphics content manager etc...) in their factory methods.

How should I share the memory module? Would passing an instance of CMemoryManager to a DLL for all its internal allocations be dangerous? What are the risks, and how can I avoid them? My reason for using a DLL/SO for the memory module (as opposed to a static lib/archive) is that I would like to load the memory module dynamically. This way I can profile various implementations and possibly release more efficient versions in the future.

For example,

```
// Win32 Version
Result Engine::LoadModules()
{
    HRESULT input_library = LoadLibrary(input_library_path);
    if(input_library == NULL)
    {
        return Result::Failure(L"InputLibrary Failed To Load");
    }

    InputFactoryFuncPtr InputFactoryFunction;
    InputFactoryFunction = (InputFactoryFuncPtr)GetProcAddress(input_library,"MakeFactory");

    input_factory = InputFactoryFunction(memory_manager,...);
    if(input_factory == NULL)
    {
        return Result::Failure(L"InputLibrary::MakeFactory Failed");
    }

    // The input_factory allocates memory using the memory_manager here.
    keyboard = input_factory.create_keyboard();

    return Result::Success;
}
```

In other words, are there risks associated with passing & using the memory manager instance across DLL boundries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"there should only be one instance of the CMemoryManager class" This sounds like Singleton Pattern. Back to the core Question, It sounds like Plugin architecture is what you need. I would make both memory manager class and All other modules Dynamic files with different type 
i.e

```
typedef enum {PLUGIN_TYPE_MEMMGR, PLUGIN_TYPE_NORMAL}PType;
```

then in constructor for Plugins you pass type (you can later have more than one memory manager). Then There will be plugin manager which will be created by engine and will be another parameter passed to each plugin. Manager should have ONLY one instance of plugin with MEMMGR type (you can extend it to have more than one in future with little change in code). The Plugin Manager should be a singleton so that each plugin will have the same instance of memory manager.

```
class PManager{
public:
  PManager(){
     m_memoryManager = LoadPluginSomeHow(PLUGIN_TYPE_MEMMGR);
  }
  CMemoryManager* GetMemoryManager(){
   return m_memoryManager;
}
//other code to do task

private:
  CMemoryManager* m_memoryManager;
};
```

I'm not in position to explain better, may be I will edit and add information but you can have an idea by reading [this thread](http://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=28098&start=15)

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply Stefano. Unfortunately, my question is about how valid/secure passing a memory manager from one DLL or SO to another is. Apologies if this wasn't clear (I've had very little sleep). I'm adding some code to the original question to help clarify matters.

Comment: you pass objects between DLLs and that is fine if and only if each DLL have mechanism of generating objects in itself. Then pass pointers to those objects and destroy them in same dll it wwas created. This is because of ABI/compiler problems. I will edit once Im on PC

Comment: Thank you again Stefano. That answers my question. This is my first time writing a memory manager as opposed to using an in house one. With that in mind, I will make the memory manager library static and having each plug in library use its own instance of the manager internally.